# Iframe not integrating (with stripe ) over HTTPS despite being on same domain

Tags: html, http, iframe, stripe-payments, server-side-rendering

I am trying to get a payment page to render from the server-side. I am using React for the web, My server is hosted over HTTPS and I'm trying to use an IFrame to load the payment page over the react application. Since I need to make an API call to the server, And I MUST use a header for authentication, I am calling the API and the html it returns I am using for the srcDoc property for the IFrame.

```
// example code
// in React 
async example() {
    const htmlContent = await makeAPICall();
    // htmlContent is the html from response
    this.setState({"html": htmlContent})
}

render() {
    if (this.state.html) {
       return (
            <iframe
            srcDoc = {this.state.html}
            title, width, height
            ></iframe>
        )
    } else return null
 }
```

I am using stripe for collecting payment information. While I was in development, This was working fine. I call the API, asynchronously load the HTML into the iframe as srcdoc and continue within the Iframe. But the moment I had deployed in production using live keys, This Iframe fails to have stripe load the payment information, Displaying only a cryptic message saying "All payments must be done over HTTPS". Now, My server is using HTTPS, The web is hosted from the server itself, Communicating over the same origin over HTTPS, But for some reason,  the Iframe itself is not able to have Stripe to load the contents.

I had tried messing around with the Iframe properties ( considering that I am not using the *src* property) and I have come to no solution yet. I am stuck in production - With the payment page being a blocker. 
I appreciate all the help I can get.

Thanks

I have tried replicating this issue using ngrok over my localhost. With the approach  I was following, I was not able to load it using the *srcdoc* property.  What did work for me was when I gave a URL for the Iframe within the *src* property but this wouldn't work for me because I need to pass the header with every request I make.

Expected stripe to load over HTTPS from the same origin using Iframe and srcDoc but it fails to do so.

Answer (score 4):

> considering that I am not using the src property

When you do this, the browser will make the URL/origin of the document in the iframe be `about:blank`, or `about:srcdoc` in this case. You can see this demonstrated in the snippet. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#otherwise-steps-for-iframe-or-frame-elements

```html
<iframe srcdoc="
<script src='https://js.stripe.com/v3/'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function(){
  var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx');
  document.getElementById('display').textContent = window.location.href;
}
</script>
<p id='display'></p>
"></iframe>
```

The problem there is this means Stripe's JavaScript doesn't know that your page is really loading on `https://example.com`, since it probably looks at the window location it is loaded in and uses that to display the error you see(since there are very good reasons to only host a payment form over https). If you check the console for the above snippet you can see Stripe's JavaScript gives a warning because it thinks it's not loading over https. Presumably if I started using production keys the warning upgrades to an error.

Looks like someone else ran into a [similar issue](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/issues/293), and the fix is to use the `src` attribute and change your design to fit. Possibly you could set the `src` attribute to an intermediate page that dynamically adds content from your server to the iframe(or just do this directly on the parent page since you wouldn't need a frame), or change your backend server to use more standard cookie/session based authentication instead of a custom header.

Comment: Looks like you're right. As you had directed, Checking the properties against the iframe gave the URL as about:srcdoc. Additionally, When I logged the window.location, On the caller it was the https and the domain but on the iframe it was 'about:srcdoc '. I used the src property against the URL and got it to work. I'm not very satisfied with this fallback, But c'est la vie. Thanks a lot for your help.